# Django - edit default graphene Set query

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python

i am building a django application with graphql and i have two models

Column Model:

```
class Column(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Task Model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    column = models.ForeignKey(Column, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    position = models.IntegerField()
```

and i have a query to query all Columns and their tasks

```
class ColumnType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Column

class Query(object):
    columns = graphene.List(ColumnType)

    def resolve_columns(self, info, **kwargs):
        return Column.objects.all()
```

and i can query this by:

```
{
    columns {
        id
        taskSet{
            content
        }
    }
}
```

but by doing this i cant add fields to taskSet function so i want to add a filter that will get only the first 20 tasks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always want to show only the first 20 results you can try this:

```
class Query(object):
    columns = graphene.List(ColumnType)

    def resolve_columns(self, info, **kwargs):
        return Column.objects.all()[0:20]
```

Or if you want to give give a filter number when you run the query you can try something like this:

```
class Query(object):
    columns = graphene.List(ColumnType, myFilter=Int())

    def resolve_columns(self, info, **kwargs):
        my_filter = kwargs.get('myFilter')
        if my_filter is not None:
            return Column.objects.all()[0:my_filter]
        return None
```

And call it like:

```
{
    columns {
        id
        taskSet(myFilter:20){
            content
        }
    }
}
```